# TFS "missing" changeset

Tags: tfs

Can anyone tell me where my changeset has gone? I'm certain I checked a change to a file in, however in history there is no mention of me, my changes howver magically appear in a later change by another developer!!!!

Is it possible for TFS administrator "delete" a changeset so it no longer appears in history?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - there's a feature of TFS called "Rollback" that allows an administrator to undo a change so it's like it never happened:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/16/hidden-gem-in-tfs-2010-how-to-rollback-a-changeset-with-tf-rollback.aspx

It's only available to administrators, and only from the command line, so most people don't even know it exists, and you have to be very intentional about using it (ie it's not possible to "accidentally" roll something back). In general, the system is designed so that history is always preserved, but if somebody accidentally checks in their 14GB MP3 library, there needs to be a way to remove that from the repository.

However, since you're seeing your changes in later files, this likely isn't what happened. I've never heard of something like this happening on a system I've managed, though it could be an obscure bug - what version/build/update are you running? Is it fully patched? Can you get a version number?

Also, when you click on a file you updated as part of this check-in and look at the history, is your update in the list? Are you only missing your update when you look at the folder/project history? There are multiple methods and scopes you can view history for, and I'd be interested to know if your check-in is showing up in some, but not in all the places you expect to see it.

Comment: Ahhhaaaaa. Mystery unravelling, My changes were made in file A. Overlord removes from file A and refactors into file B(in a different changeset) so my code magically appears in file B......

Comment: Glad to hear they didn't just vanish :)